# how to bypass subresources integrity check by autoresponder and fiddler rules

Tags: fiddler, subresource-integrity

I want to use fiddler to changed the javascript files

I've solve the cors policy, but I don't know how to set the rules to allow my script bypass the subresources integrity checks, what should I write in the autoresponder to solve this kind of issues.

[image]

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute play:1
for resource 'https://a.gamelet.online/gassets/resource/d7ad4a5.../m
odules.js' With computed SHA-256 integrity
' 9AoQiDzp9rKuhtfbTQtj1N4Rh7kqUtxfLdrVOuef7dw='. The resource has
been blocked.
```

when I want to replace a javascript file with fiddler by bpu or autoresponder just faced this kind of issue,

here the site I wan't to rerplace it's edior script to enable to add more button and new feature
[https://twrolecgeditor.gamelet.online/?version=0.15.16](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: I always use incognito mode to let fiddler capture the javascript file and modify them, this method always work before. until this site add a subresource-integrity so I have to deal with cors, csp, integrity hash when I want to change the client side javascripts. I want to know any method to allow me to change client side javascript.